# Compiling a custom RPi kernel for QEMU

Tags: qemu

I just compiled a custom kernel for Raspberry pi. However, when trying to boot it up using QEMU I seem to be getting errors as shown [here](http://pastebin.com/3uwnvrt2). Is there anything obvious that I'm doing wrong? Is there any more information I can provide to make the problem clearer?

Comment: what command are you using to run qemu? I found that some of the parameters are very specific, like -m 256 being the most memory you could allocate.

Comment: @rob The command I'm using is : qemu-system-arm -kernel vmlinux -hda kernel.img -machine versatilepb

Comment: Not sure if it will help but here was what I used witha prebuild raspbian image qemu-system-arm.exe -kernel kernel-qemu -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1" -hda raspbian.img

Comment: I have added a new question about qemu and crosscompiled raspberry kernel with busybox in initramfs: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/56302/qemu-2-7-0-for-the-raspi2-machine-do-not-show-the-second-tty-console-only-the

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the same thing, I haven't ran into this exact problem, but I found that this resource: https://github.com/dhruvvyas90/qemu-rpi-kernel, if you look at the README's in the tools directory, it indicates that the kernel must be compiled with specific hardware disabled since it is not emulated in qemu. It appears that the repo also contains a script for automatically compiling the kernel for qemu. Hope this helps!